# Stop the lock screen for a while if possible

Tags: android

I want to override the lock screen button somehow. The idea is that I want to keep my screen awake for a while, and I did so

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
                "MyWakelockTag");
        wakeLock.acquire();
    }
```

Anyway, I have a flip cover on my phone, and when I put the flip on, my phone is get locked. How could I stop the locking screen event when I put the flip cover on? That's why I need to know if it's possible to stop the lock screen functionality for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Flipcover, you have to check the [SensorManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html) and for the Power/Lock Button you can try this -

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    switch (action) {
        case Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF:
            BaseActivity.unlockScreen();
            break;

        case Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON:
            // and do whatever you need to do here
            BaseActivity.clearScreen();
    }
  }
}
```

But I'm not sure it'll work